Cannot connect to vpn after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04
I have not managed to get VPN working since upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. All the algorithms set and IPsec tunnel to L2TP host enabled. PAP as authentication methods selected. Everything is similar to configs used in 22.04, but it's not working.
2024-05-15T13:04:48.427386+03:00 hp-local systemd[1]: Started ipsec.service - Internet Key Exchange (IKE) Protocol Daemon for IPsec.  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.434936+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197075]: 002 listening for IKE messages  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.435006+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197075]: 002 forgetting secrets  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.435046+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197075]: 002 loading secrets from "<path-to-secrets>"  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.435097+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197075]: 002 loading secrets from "<path-to-secrets-file>" 
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440326+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: debugging mode enabled  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440395+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: end of file <path-to-ipsec-conf>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440426+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: Loading conn <unique-identifier>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440884+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" modecfgdns=<unset>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440914+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" modecfgdomains=<unset>   
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440940+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" modecfgbanner=<unset>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.440984+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" mark=<unset>   
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441007+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" mark-in=<unset>     
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441030+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" mark-out=<unset>     
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441115+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" vti_iface=<unset>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441145+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" redirect-to=<unset>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441173+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" accept-redirect-to=<unset>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441210+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" esp=aes128-sha1,3des-sha1!  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441245+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: conn: "<unique-identifier>" ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp2048,aes256-sha2_256-modp1536,aes256-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-ecp256,3des-sha1-modp2048  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441274+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: opening file: <path-to-ipsec-conf>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441303+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: loading named conns: <unique-identifier>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441328+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: resolving family=IPv4 src=(null) gateway=<not-set> peer <IP-Address-Redacted>  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441354+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: seeking NOTHING  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441379+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: resolving family=IPv4 src=<IP-Address-Redacted> gateway=<not-set> peer (null)
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441402+03:00 hp-local NetworkManager[197081]: seeking NOTHING  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441516+03:00 hp-local nm-l2tp-service[196756]: Could not establish IPsec connection.  
2024-05-15T13:04:48.441577+03:00 hp-local nm-l2tp-service[196756]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed  


If you can connect to your provider and browse the net without vpn, the fault lies with your vpn. Could be one of many reasons. Suggest you contact your vpn support team.

Can't tell from the log output if you are using libreswan or strongswan. Your Phase 2 with the exclamation mark (!) seems to be for strongswan, but the Phase 1 seems to be for libreswan as it doesn't have modp1024 and doesn't have an exclamation mark.
Anyway, phase 1 (i.e. Main Mode) seems to be failing. You could try deleting whatever you set for phase 1 & 2 and trying again. If it needs modp1024, you'll need to use strongswan as the libreswan that ships with 24.04 doesn't support it. You can also try newer package from https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp

I too see the issue with VPN, I'm quite certain my configuration is correct and I see it working in Ubuntu 23.10. I filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-l2tp/+bug/2068687

Douglas suggested to try:
`sudo apt install xl2tpd`
`sudo apt purge go-l2tp`

which helped in my case

@ĽubomírMlích solution worked for me, any reasoning for this to work? anything wrong with go-l2tp that xl2tpd fixes?

@stigma see launchpad bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-l2tp/+bug/2068687
